# Problem trying to use spring security with my jsp aplication

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security

It's seems so easy to use spring security following a tutorial, but when I try to do the same with this app I can get it to work (I must admit that I haven't written ) .

**/-----------------Edit-------------------/**

Now with the help of some great people, I finally got the application to ask the user to authenticate himself,but now I've run into a new problem: When I try to access the application using one of the users listed below(**applicationContext-security.xml**), I get this message :

[image]

Here's `web.xml` code:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>  
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>    
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping> 
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>  
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>  
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/sinacceso.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

**context.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Test01"/>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
    <!-- GENERALES -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="/index.htm" class="paginas.index"/>
    <bean name="secure/villancicos.htm" class="paginas.villancicos"/>
    <bean name="secure/administracion.htm" class="paginas.administracion"/>
</beans>
```

**applicationContext-security.xml:**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/index.htm" filters="none" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/secure/administracion.htm" access="ROLE_SUPERVISOR" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <form-login />
        <anonymous />
        <http-basic />
        <logout logout-success-url="/index.htm" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager alias="myAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
            <user-service>
                <user name="rod" password="a564de63c2d0da68cf47586ee05984d7" authorities="ROLE_SUPERVISOR, ROLE_USER, ROLE_TELLER" />
                <user name="dianne" password="65d15fe9156f9c4bbffd98085992a44e" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_TELLER" />
                <user name="scott" password="2b58af6dddbd072ed27ffc86725d7d3a" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <user name="peter" password="22b5c9accc6e1ba628cedc63a72d57f8" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

This application is currently using spring 2.5 with spring-security-2.0.4 (the same version from the tutorial I've been following).

Comment: looks like you are using version 3 schemas: spring-beans-3.0.xsd and spring-security-3.0.xsd and

Comment: @Ritesh- and which ones am I supposed to use? :( Cause I've already tried with spring-beans-2.0.xsd and spring-security-2.0.1.xsd, but I keep getting the same error :(

Comment: Well, if you are using Spring 2.5 then it should be spring-beans-2.5.xsd. spring-security-2.0.4.xsd should be used with spring-security-2.0.4. Also, do you see any error stack in any log file?

Comment: What application server are you trying to deploy to?

Comment: @Ritesh- I tried what you told me, but nothing changed and as for the tomcat log, I've updated my question with the full log output. Please take at look at it :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried what the error suggests and added an alias attribute to your authentication-manager? Something like:

```
<authentication-manager alias="myAuthenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I did what you suggested and it worked, I mean I don't get the error messages anymore, but I also had to change back the version of the schemas(Otherwise, I got a lot more error messages), so now I'm using   spring-beans-**3.0**.xsd and spring-security-**3.0**.xsd, but even after all those changes I can't get spring security to work,it just didn't do anything at all(I can still access the pages without logging in)  :(

Comment: @eddy How are you accessing the application? Can you give one URL of your page as an example? like http://server/myApp/Layout/myPage.htm.

Comment: @eddy: That URL doesn't have /Layout in the path, and those are the only URLs you've told spring security to intercept.

Comment: @Ryan- You were right, I removed /Layout and now everytime I try to access anything other than the index page, I'm asked to log in,which it's great, but now something else seems not to be working properly,please take a look at the screenshot of the error message that I've added